# python nested list sort based on 2nd value of the list is not working properly when it has value 10

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists, secondary-indexes

here is my code for hackerrank nested list problem in python
problem link:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem?isFullScreen=true

**code:**

```
def sort(sub_li):
    return(sorted(sub_li, key = lambda x: x[1]))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=int(input ())
    stu=[]
    record=[]
    for i in range(0,x):   
        stu.append(input())
        stu.append(input())
        record.append(stu)
        stu = []
    
    namelist = []
     
    sortedrecord = sort(record)
    print(sortedrecord)
    value = 0
    for i,j in sortedrecord:
        if j>sortedrecord[0][1]:
            
            value = j
            break
    
    for i,j in sortedrecord:
        if j==value:
            namelist.append(i)  
    
    namelist.sort()
    
    for i in namelist:
        print(i)
```

problem is that the sort fuction is not sorting properly when it has a score of 10

sample input:

```
4
Shadab
8
Varun
8.9
Sarvesh
9.5
Harsh
10
```

output:

```
[['Harsh', '10'], ['Shadab', '8'], ['Varun', '8.9'], ['Sarvesh', '9.5']]
Shadab
```

note: i have tried alternative sorting ways ,but the condition remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lexicographic order, `10` comes befor `8`, because `1` is before `8`

You need to convert to `float` to get it work like you expect

1. at input

   ```
    stu.append(input())
    stu.append(float(input()))
   ```
2. or at use

   ```
   def sort(sub_li):
       return sorted(sub_li, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
   ```